# ms access code is not working for .xls file TT_confidential is not updated on generated excel file, variable is not declared msoPropertyTypeString

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkVDV.gif)[Invalid procedure call or argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMjK9.gif)

Comment: If you really have the .Add command running over two lines, need line continuation character: `=False, _`

Comment: I tested code (with above edit as well as removing extraneous text comments) and it runs without error. However, I cannot verify any properties were actually changed. I don't know how to view them.

Comment: Run time error 5 Invalid Procedure call or argument for below line i have mentioned that line in single line mwb.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="Classification", LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:="TT_Confidential"

Comment: Should edit question to show error message there. As I said, I do not get error. Did you make the edit as advised earlier?

Comment: i don't have 10 reputations that why I have attached above screenshot, invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Error message and code should be text not image. Image shows .Add command is all on one line. Again, I cannot replicate issue.

Comment: actually yellow marked line I got Invalid call or argument ,In MS Access references, Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library is already marked.